# myMap is there a way to authenticate

Tags: javascript, geoxml3

Is there a way to able to get the data even it was restricted sharing. I'm currently using mymap.

```
var  src = "https://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?mid={id}&forcekml=1"

geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
      map: map,
      infoWindow: infowindow,
      singleInfoWindow: true,
      afterParse: useTheData
     });
     geoXml.parse(src);
      
     function useTheData(doc) {
      var geoXmlDoc = doc[0];
      console.log(geoXmlDoc)
    }
```

My error is cors.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?{id}&forcekml=1' from origin 
'http://localhost:5501/' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: You need to retrieve the data through a proxy

Comment: I don't have experience using proxy. what should i do?